# Something went wrong while saving the category Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, database, category, url-rewrite

There are many threads with almost the same title, but i could not find a solution for it

I have a following structure in magento 2 for categories

[image]

Among them i can save all the categories apart from the selected Home Decor or it's parent Products. Both of these categories give me "Something went wrong while saving this category" error

I checked my expection.log in "var/log/" magento folder and i get the following message

[image]

One thing i have noticed is, if for these particular categories, if i switch "Anchor" (under Display Settings) option on, i get the issue, and if i switch them off i get the success message.

This led me to believe the issue is in URL rewrites, but i cannot truncate that table as we have written a lot of custom redirects within it.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: it can be a mod security issue , check with your server settings

Comment: mod security issue? please elaborate.. i am quite naive with server mods

Comment: which server you are using ? read about it here https://blog.nexcess.net/2012/09/14/mod_security-and-content-management-systems/